Local Action by Group Scheme (Milne's Algebraic Groups)
I have a question about following proof from Milne's book "Algebraic Groups: the theory of group schemes of finite type over a field", Chapter 8, proposition 8.9:

PROPOSITION 8.9. Let $G \times X \to X$ be an algebraic group acting on an irreducible algebraic scheme $X$ over base field $k$ (i.e. $k$ - scheme of finite type). If the action is faithful and there is a fixed point $p \in X(k) = \text{Hom}(\text{Spec}(k),X)$, then $G$ is affine.


PROOF. Because $G$ fixes $P$, it acts on the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ at $P$. For $n \in \Bbb N$,
the formation of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_P^{n+1}$ commutes with extension of the base, and so the
action of $G$ defines homomorphisms $G(R) \to \text{Aut}(R \otimes_k \mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_P^{n+1})$ for all
small $k$-algebras $R$. These are natural in $R$, and so arise from a homomorphism $\rho_n: G \to \text{GL}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_P^{n+1}}$
of algebraic groups. Let $H_n := \text{Ker}(\rho_n)$ , and let $H$ denote
the intersection of the descending sequence of algebraic subgroups $... \supset H_n \supset H_{n+1} \supset...$. Because $G$ is noetherian, there exists a $n_0$ such that $H = H_n$ for all $n \ge n_0$.


Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the sheaf of ideals in $\mathcal{O}_X$ corresponding to the closed algebraic
subscheme $X^H$ of $X$ (scheme of fixed point exists as closed subscheme is shown somewhere in the book). Then $\mathcal{I} \cdot \mathcal{O}_X \subset \mathfrak{m}_P^n$ for all $n \ge n_0$, and so $\mathcal{I} \cdot \mathcal{O}_X \subset \cap_n \mathfrak{m}_P^n$,
which is zero by the Krull intersection theorem (CA 3.16). It follows that $X^H$
contains an open neighbourhood of $P$. As $X^H$ is closed and $X$ is irreducible,
$X^H$ equals $X$. Therefore $H = \{e\}$ (neutral element), and the representation of $G$ on $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_P^{n+1}$ is
faithful for all $n \ge n_0$. This means that
$\rho_n: G \to \text{GL}_{\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_P^{n+1}}$
is a monomorphism,
hence a closed immersion (5.34), and so $G$ is affine.

Question: Where in the proof we really need $P$ to assume to be $k$-rational point and not say any $L$-valued point for $L/k$ finite field extension of $k$? Not that such $L$-valued point corresponds to local map $\mathcal{O}_{X,x_L} \to L$ of $k$-algebras where $x_L$ is the kernel of this map, ie a prime ideal of $X$.
And going step by step trough the proof it seems to make no difference if assume $P$ to be $k$ or $L$-rational, or do I missing something?
Note, that using fppf-descent the statement about affinity of $G$ is still true it we not assume $P$ to be rational: Just assume $P \in X(L)$, and apply the Proposition to base change $X \otimes_k L$ instead and use fppf descent as affinity can be showed on fppf cover.
So the statement itself on affinity of $G$ seemingly not requires $P$ to be $k$-rational. But my question is if (and where) the techniques in the presented proof itself somewhere explicitly going to exploit that $P$ is $k$-rational.
It seems to me that exactly the same proof would go literally trough (without even small modifications!) independently if $P$ is $k$- or $L$-valued point for $L/k$ finite extension. Or do I missing something?
